# In LWC on page load how can we read the Combobox field value and field value Id

Tags: lightning-web-components

In LWC while loading the page, how can we read the Combobox's default value.

I want to read the value Id and value text from Combobox.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={sobjectApiName} record-id={recordId} onload={handleOnLoad}>
        <div>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="ProductType__c" class="productType"></lightning-input-field>
        </div>
     </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>

handleOnLoad() {
    let productTypeValue = this.template.querySelector('.productType');
    console.log('ProductTypeId__c Vale:' + **productTypeValue.value** + ' --> ' + **productTypeValue.text**);
}
```

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. This question is not related to `community` or `salesforcedx`.

Comment: Hi @Mahesh I cant see checkbox in above code. Can you please be more specific. Thanks

Comment: I want to read the text value from lookup box using javascript from handleOnLoad functionsomething like this.template.querySelector('.productType').text() which is not working

Comment: @MaheshJoshi You seem to have two accounts by mistake. Please use the Contact Us link at the bottom of this page to have them merged for you. Thanks.